# How to limit range of columns from a table with VBA and Access in a select case structure

Tags: excel, vba, vba6

I have the code below and I need to import the data from a table in the range of "A:K".

```
Function ImportExport(ByVal template As String) As Boolean

    Dim Name As String
    Dim Code As String
    Dim table As String
    Dim Sheet As String
    
    If Dir(CurrentProject.Path & "\Folder1\*" & template & "*") = "" Then ImportExport = True
        Else
    Name = Dir(CurrentProject.Path & "\Folder1\*" & template & "*")
            
     Select Case template
                Case “Reality
                Code = “Try1”
                table = “secondTable"
                
                'Sheet = Sheets("Table_needs!”).Range("A:K")
                Sheet = "Table_needs!"
```

What I need is sth like it:

```
Sheet = Sheets("Table_needs!”).Range("A:K")
```

But it doesn't work in this structure. can anyone help?

Comment: Is the ! in the tab name? Sheet is defined as string, not range.  `Dim Sheet As Range`

Comment: No, but anyway I tried with both "!" and without "!". but the result was the same

Comment: Tnx. but still when I concat Sheet = Sheets("Table_needs!”) and .Range("A:K")--> it shows me a coding error (the lines will be red) 
How can I write it correctly?
 Sheet = Sheets("Table_needs!”).Range("A:K")

Comment: What do you want the output `sheet` to be a string of the address of the range or the range?

Comment: The VBA code was written by someone else and I need to change this part.
What I need is to import data from a table sheet ONLY for the columns of A:K

Comment: It's difficult to fix that part without knowing what happens below the code you posted. Also you need to fix all those "smart" quotes in the code.